# How to execute a mongoDB shell script via Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, shell, sharding

I am working on my class project in which I want to demonstrate the use of mongoDB sharding. I am using mongoDB node.js native driver. I got to know there is no sharding functionality in this driver. So, I have to write shell script to do sharding. So, Is it possible to do this somehow like this:

**node myfile.js (executes my shell script and run my code)**

Comment: Try out some code and post it here if you have problems.  Someone could post an answer for you but then you won't learn (which is the point of going to class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you already have a shell script, why not execute that through the [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module. Just use the below function to run the script that you have.

[child_process.execFileSync(file[, args][, options])](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfilesync_file_args_options)

Note that the script should have run permissions(use `chmod a+x script` otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you consider using npm run scripts?
if you want the script to run standalone, add scripts with test/start or both to your package json,

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "node mytestfile.js",
    "start": "node ./myfile --param1 --param2"
  },
```

and `run npm run test` or `npm run start` which can execute the script file. this way you can even pass parameters to the script.

or the elegant child_process way,

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");
exec("node myfile.js", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

stderr and stdout will show the progress of the script as you build further.
hope this helps.